# How do I access DLC “collectibles” in Saints Row Reboot?

Tags: saints-row-2022

Several of the items in the “Collectibles” list say “Unlockable with DLC”.  However, as far as I can tell, I have all available DLC installed.  How do I get access to these items?

I am on PS5, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I never found a way to have them unlock on the list itself, but they seem to be accessible when I go into the "Choose what to place here" menu, at least.